# My code works but I don't know why

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT TOP 100
        o.[Incident ID], 
        o.[Affected CI], 
        o.Title, 
        o.[Description], 
        d.[DB NAME],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.[Incident ID] ORDER BY o.[Incident ID]) rn
        FROM Oracle_Incident_Data.dbo.Oracle_Incidents AS O 
        LEFT JOIN Oracle_Incident_Data.dbo.DB_NAMES_ORA$ AS D 
        ON CONCAT(COALESCE(o.[Affected CI],' '), COALESCE(o.[Title],' '), COALESCE(o.[Description],' ')) LIKE '%' + d.[DB NAME] + '%'
    ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Partition was recommended to me by a friend to fix an issue I had with the previous query returning ever match, not find a match in DB Name and moving to the next incident.  The problem is now I don't really understand what it is doing and I want to tweak the matching.  Next I want to figure out how to make it join the longest matching string, but I need to understand how partition works in this query first.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: your syntax suggets other db than mysql,probably sql server

Comment: it is sql server sorry, bad tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windowing functions are confusing at first. No doubt.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.[Incident ID] ORDER BY o.[Incident ID]) rn
```

That line will create a row_number starting at `1` and ascending for each record. It will start over at `1` for each new `o.[Incident ID]` that it comes across in the result set of the query. It determines the ordering of the numbering by the `o.[Incident ID]` as well.

For instance:

```
 rn   IncidentID
 1       A
 2       A
 3       A
 1       B
 2       B
 1       C
 2       C
 3       C
```

**To see what it's doing take the subquery out and run it by itself, sorting the results of the query by `o.[Incident ID]`. It will become clear then.**

Your main query with the `WHERE rn = 1` then filters out only the records where the `ROW_NUMBER` is `1`.

All that being said, I don't think it's correct the way it's written. `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` really shouldn't be the same. It will cause arbritrary numbering when you have multiple records in your recordset with the same `o.[Incident ID]`. And those results may change each time you run the query depending on how your database is fetching data from the underlying tables.

Instead you should probably `ORDER BY` something that will actually yield an ORDER when you partition by `o.[Incident ID]`. Generally this is a DATE or some measure field, but it could be something arbitrary like your Title or Description too.

Comment: Very nice and simple explanation of the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)  Helps those especially when they have context with their own data as opposed to just... here's an answer and not understanding the context.